# How do I run if statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table in my MySQL database, having phones and names
like:

- phone1, name1
- phone2, name2

etc...

and I'm listing names, but I want to replace a name which is null with a phone in my results

like `IF(name IS NULL){SELECT phone AS name}else{SELECT name} FROM users`

and get:

- name1
- name2
- phone3
- name4

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 3):

The `coalesce` function seems like an easy way to achieve this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(name, phone) FROM users
```

Comment: Is there any difference to `IFNULL`? (I'm used to TSQL `ISNULL`)

Comment: @Filburt `ifnull` only takes two arguments, while `coalesce` takes a variable number of arguments and returns the first non-`null` value. Additionally, `coalesce` is an standard ANSI function, while, AFAIK, `ifnull` is not.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
SELECT id, 
   IF(name IS NULL, phone, name) as name
FROM report
```

Here you can find more info

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the COALESE function, or for more complex IF statements, you can use `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN phone ELSE name END AS name_or_phone
```

If you're involving multiple tables, join them, and reference them in the CASE:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN users.name IS NULL THEN phones.phone ELSE users.name END AS name_or_phone
FROM users
LEFT JOIN phones on phones.user_id = users.user_id
```

See [Case statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) on MySQL Docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF (SELECT name FROM tbl_your WHERE name IS NULL) SELECT phone AS name
ELSE SELECT name;
```